# .Netcore Api Postman 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, api, postman, asp.net-core-3.1

A post request from my API to my database through postman gives me this response:
{
"message": "Invalid object name 'Accounts'."
}

These are my C# codes i don't know what i did wrong or what i am missing. please help.

1. AccountsController.

   using AutoMapper;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using Africanbiomedtests.Entities;
   using Africanbiomedtests.Models.Accounts;
   using Africanbiomedtests.Services;

   ```
    namespace Africanbiomedtests.Controllers
    {
        [ApiController]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        public class AccountsController : BaseController
        {
             private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
             private readonly IMapper _mapper;

             public AccountsController(
                 IAccountService accountService,
                 IMapper mapper)
             {
                 _accountService = accountService;
                 _mapper = mapper;
            }

            [HttpPost("authenticate")]
            public ActionResult<AuthenticateResponse> Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model)
            {
                var response = _accountService.Authenticate(model, ipAddress());
                setTokenCookie(response.RefreshToken);
                return Ok(response);
            }

            [HttpPost("refresh-token")]
            public ActionResult<AuthenticateResponse> RefreshToken()
            {
                var refreshToken = Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];
                var response = _accountService.RefreshToken(refreshToken, ipAddress());
                setTokenCookie(response.RefreshToken);
                return Ok(response);
            }

            [Authorize]
            [HttpPost("revoke-token")]
            public IActionResult RevokeToken(RevokeTokenRequest model)
            {
                // accept token from request body or cookie
                var token = model.Token ?? Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    return BadRequest(new { message = "Token is required" });

                // users can revoke their own tokens and admins can revoke any tokens
                if (!Account.OwnsToken(token) && Account.Role != Role.Admin)
                    return Unauthorized(new { message = "Unauthorized" });

                _accountService.RevokeToken(token, ipAddress());
                return Ok(new { message = "Token revoked" });
            }

            [HttpPost("register")]
            public IActionResult Register(RegisterRequest model)
            {
                _accountService.Register(model, Request.Headers["origin"]);
                return Ok(new { message = "Registration successful, please check your email for verification instructions" });
            }

            [HttpPost("verify-email")]
            public IActionResult VerifyEmail(VerifyEmailRequest model)
            {
                _accountService.VerifyEmail(model.Token);
                return Ok(new { message = "Verification successful, you can now login" });
            }

            [HttpPost("forgot-password")]
            public IActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordRequest model)
            {
                _accountService.ForgotPassword(model, Request.Headers["origin"]);
                return Ok(new { message = "Please check your email for password reset instructions" });
            }

            [HttpPost("validate-reset-token")]
            public IActionResult ValidateResetToken(ValidateResetTokenRequest model)
            {
                _accountService.ValidateResetToken(model);
                return Ok(new { message = "Token is valid" });
            }

            [HttpPost("reset-password")]
            public IActionResult ResetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest model)
            {
                _accountService.ResetPassword(model);
                return Ok(new { message = "Password reset successful, you can now login" });
            }

            [Authorize(Role.Admin)]
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult<IEnumerable<AccountResponse>> GetAll()
            {
                var accounts = _accountService.GetAll();
                return Ok(accounts);
            }

            [Authorize]
            [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
            public ActionResult<AccountResponse> GetById(int id)
            {
                // users can get their own account and admins can get any account
                if (id != Account.Id && Account.Role != Role.Admin)
                    return Unauthorized(new { message = "Unauthorized" });

                var account = _accountService.GetById(id);
                return Ok(account);
            }

            [Authorize(Role.Admin)]
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult<AccountResponse> Create(CreateRequest model)
            {
                var account = _accountService.Create(model);
                return Ok(account);
            }

            [Authorize]
            [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
            public ActionResult<AccountResponse> Update(int id, UpdateRequest model)
            {
                // users can update their own account and admins can update any account
                if (id != Account.Id && Account.Role != Role.Admin)
                    return Unauthorized(new { message = "Unauthorized" });

                // only admins can update role
                if (Account.Role != Role.Admin)
                    model.Role = null;

                var account = _accountService.Update(id, model);
                return Ok(account);
            }

            [Authorize]
            [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
            public IActionResult Delete(int id)
            {
                // users can delete their own account and admins can delete any account
                if (id != Account.Id && Account.Role != Role.Admin)
                    return Unauthorized(new { message = "Unauthorized" });

                _accountService.Delete(id);
                return Ok(new { message = "Account deleted successfully" });
            }

            // helper methods

            private void setTokenCookie(string token)
            {
                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
                };
                Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
            }

            private string ipAddress()
            {
                if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Forwarded-For"))
                    return Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"];
                else
                    return HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
   ```

2). Accounts Enitity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Africanbiomedtests.Entities
{
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public HealthcareProvider HealthcareProvider { get; set; }
        public string VerificationToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Verified { get; set; }
        public bool IsVerified => Verified.HasValue || PasswordReset.HasValue;
        public string ResetToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ResetTokenExpires { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PasswordReset { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
        public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }

        public bool OwnsToken(string token) 
        {
            return this.RefreshTokens?.Find(x => x.Token == token) != null;
        }
    }
}
```

3). RegisterRequest Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Africanbiomedtests.Models.Accounts
{
    public class RegisterRequest
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MinLength(6)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true")]
        public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as the code you have provided seems to be more than required to demonstrate the issue. Please also show how you are calling the API.

Comment: Have you tried first setting a breakpoint on the first line of the controller method and then stepping through the code line-by-line to find where the issue is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help John, i realized i hadn't done my EF database migration so the fault was from me. Did the migrations and its now working.